# How to determine a blinking cursor (caret) position VB.net

Tags: vb.net, cursor

How to determine blinking cursor position x,y on the form?

EDIT:

Okay, after many years I decided to take a look at my question. The description is very short and doesn't tell anything. I remember, was doing a desktop application for a medical device with automatic suggestions of names, while the beginning of a patient name is typed. I needed a list-control to have VS like suggestions just after the caret.

Comment: Do you want to know which field is focused?

Comment: You are probably talking about the *caret*, not the mouse cursor.  Use the form's ActiveControl to find the control with the focus.

Comment: Yes Mr. @HansPassant you're right, I'd looking for caret position in Internet whole day. At last I made this code and it worked. ActiveControl command from your advice was more useful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For this I used `yourTextBox.GetPositionFromCharIndex(CharacterIndexAsIntegerTypeHere)`

ListBox is moving on X axis with TextBox characters:

```
Dim Lstb as new ListBox
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged  
  With Lstb
    .size = new size(50,50)
    .BackColor = Color.aqua
    .location = New Point(TextBox1.Location.X + TextBox1.GetPositionFromCharIndex(TextBox1.Text.Length - 1).X,  TextBox1.Location.Y + 50)
  End with    
  Controls.Add(Lstb)
End Sub
```